# Is there any method to solve log functions in sympy and get answer without ConditionSet

Tags: python, sympy, equation

I have one variable equation and want to get the values for 'y'. But only return ConditionaSet. So is there any way to get the answer or are there any errors in my code?

```
import sympy as sp

y = sp.symbols('y', real = True)
f = 5.0*y - 5.0*y/(y**2 + 36.0) - 0.397887357729738*sp.log((-2.0*y**2 - 1.0*y - 72.0)**2/(y**2 + 36.0)**2 + 36.0/(y**2 + 36.0)**2) + 0.397887357729738*sp.log((y - 2.0)**2 + 36.0)
eq = sp.Eq(f,-18.435561204278)
p = sp.solveset(eq, domain=sp.S.Reals)
print p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dealing with a univariate expression and are not getting a solution (because it is too nonlinear) it's a good idea to just use `nsolve` to give you a numerical value:

```
>>> from sympy import nsolve
>>> yy = nsolve(eq, 0); yy
-4.00000000000000
```

When you try to substitute this into `eq` you will get False. But rewrite `eq` as an expression to see how close you actually are to 0:

```
>>> from sympy import Add
>>> g = eq.rewrite(Add)
>>> g.subs(y, yy)
1.66533453693773e-16
```

And note: it's not necessary to write your equation using `Eq`. You can just use `f +18.435561204278`, i.e. solve `Eq(x, y)` as `x - y`.